# Assign a saved datetime value in database to Datepicker value

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a kendo-datepicker in my page to insert date to table and this works fine

```
<kendo-datepicker [value]="paymentDate" [(ngModel)]="paymentDate"></kendo-datepicker>
```

I use the same web page to show the details of the saved record

```
this.paymentDate = response.paymentDate;
```

but when I assign the same value in the database to kendo-datepicker
during the page load, I gives me the following error

> The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance.

I tried to format the string but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `paymentDate` with JavaScript's `Date` object.

```
paymentDate = new Date();
// or,
paymentDate = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
```

[Checkout MDN to know furthur about `Date` object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

---

**Note:** I'm not sure the two way binding will work at this case or not. 
But the official documentation says that have `valueChange` event that you can listen.

Example:

In Template:

```
<kendo-datepicker
    (valueChange)="onChange($event)"
    [value]="paymentDate"
    >
</kendo-datepicker>
```

in Component:

```
 paymentDate = new Date();

 public onChange(value: Date): void {
    this.paymentDate= value;
  }
```